# How do I inherit from the base theme?

Tags: theming

I want to inherit from the businessplus_lite theme I use as base theme, but I can't see any CSS applicable. There is just a board template blank with articles. Can anyone tell me how I can inherit the CSS styles from businessplus_lite?

```
name: some name
type: theme
description: 'description for my theme'
core: 8.x
base theme: businessplus_lite
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you've created the `*.info.yml` file, but not yet created a `*.libraries.yml` file.

The libraries file is where you'll define which CSS is used in your theme.

See for more details on how to set this up: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme#s-example-sub-theme-fluffiness

Comment: the css of the templates located in the base theme i think , how can i call them in labraries.yml of sub-theme??

Comment: There should be no need for a libraries.yml just to inherit them, you only need this if you want to define your own libraries.

Comment: Usually you'll want some custom CSS. I'll leave that part of the answer for you or anyone else who views this problem. Plus, I'll add some info for linking it all together.

Comment: yes please bro ;)